# Select all code in MD codeblock?

Tags: regex

I need to select all code blocks in markdown document.

````
Пример создания файбера и передача ему в качестве аргумента вызываемой функции:
```
auto f = new Fiber(&foo);
```
`f.call();` вызов файбера
`Fiber.yield();` метод `yield()` класса `Fiber` вызывающий преостановку выполнение текущей функции

Пример:

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main()
{
  auto f = new Fiber(&foo);
  f.call(); // Prints Hello
  f.call(); // Prints World
}

void foo()
{
  writeln("Hello");
  Fiber.yield();
  writeln("World");
}
```

Результат:
```
> app.exe
Hello
World
````

Here is my regex https://regex101.com/r/Ya85Pk/2

But it do not working.

My language is D. https://dlang.org/library/std/regex.html

Comment: What is regex flavor? Better you post regex and sample text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script with a lazy quantifier and mode `s` (single-line mode):

```
`{3}[\r\n]+(.*?)[\r\n]+`{3}
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `` `{3}[\r\n]+ `` matches three consecutive back-ticks followed by one or more newline characters
- `(.*?)` matches lazily 0 or more of any character including newlines (because of `s` mode).

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ya85Pk/4)